# iOS Won't Rotate

Tags: iphone, ios, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate

I'm trying to add autorotation to my app, but having difficulty. I can get everything to resize (a TableView and a couple of labels), but the status bar and the rest of my window (eg: a tab bar and navigation controller) remains in portrait. I have a three view heirarchy from the window to the top ViewController and I have everything in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` set to YES, I also have everything except upside-down selected in the `Summary` section of the target's properties but it refuses to budge. This happens on the simulator and on a iPhone 4. Both are 4.3 on XCode 4. I've scoured the apple docs on view orientations but is there somewhere else I need to set this?

In my `Info.plist`, I have the following:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Comment: iOS won't rotate, or, Views won't rotate?

Comment: @EmptyStak I guess the OP meant "iOS won't rotate my views"

Comment: I know my views won't autorotate, but iOs isn't autorotating. I was under the impression that the tab bar and status bars would rotate, but the components would be squished to portrait size.

Comment: Do you have any other instances of shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in your app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually found out that if you have a UITabBarController, all of the tab views need to support rotation. Should save someone some time by remembering:

- *Nothing* will rotate until all of the tabs in a UITabBarController support rotation
- If you try to *manually resize things* when the view rotates, it's *much easier* to set the sizing properties on each control in your nib. Set anchor positions and stretching rules and most things seem to 'just work'.
- Segmented controls seem to need manual resizing in the `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` method

Answer (score 0):

In your question you state

> I have everything in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`set to YES

but I'm not sure what you mean by this. If you support all orientations then simply return `YES`

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    return YES;
}
```

It may be that what ever you have going on in here (*since you've not posted your code*) is not working as expected.

Comment: That's what I meant. In the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method, I'm just returning YES, and the code is being called which I can see from debugging, yet the view does not rotate.

Comment: If you open your `<app-name>-info.plist` manually (*with a code editor, not the property list editor*) what orientations are listed under the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` key?